# Meteor target element in child template and pass to global function

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to create a global function for removing a "selected" class when clicking outside the 'tr' element. However the event I am using is not registering the correct target element because the element resides within a child template. Here is my template code.

```
<template name="index">
        {{> header}}
        {{> navigation }}
        <section id="section-main" class="container">
            {{> yield}}
        </section>
        {{> footer}}
    </section>
</template>
```

I am attaching the click event to the "index" template. Here is the event code, with the function "deselectRow" being called...

```
Template.index.events({
    // Event: Click anywhere to deselect row
    "click": function (e) {
        // console message
        // console.log("you clicked a DOM element");
        deselectRow(e);

    }
});
```

followed by the function itself where the event is checked against the current target which I would like to be 'tr'...

```
// DESELECT Row
    deselectRow = function (e) {

        // Event: Click anywhere outside a table row element and remove selected class from tr
        if (e.currentTarget != $('tr')) {
            $('tr').removeClass('selected');
            console.log('you clicked outside a table row element')
        }
        else {
            console.log('you clicked a table row element')
        }
    };
```

My understanding is that when clicking on the row, the event handler for the "index" template is not registering that I have clicked the row (ie: using it as currentTarget). I believe this is because the row resides within the child template which is being "yielded".

How can I get the index template to recognize the 'tr' as the currentTarget?

P.S. I'm new to javascript and meteor. Thanks for your patience if I'm butchering common terminology or asking about something that should be easy to solve on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the event to `<tr>` as well as click with:

```
'click tr': function(ev){
  var currentRow = ev.target;
  $('tr').removeClass('selected'); // deselect any previously selected rows
  currentRow.addClass('selected'); // select the one just clicked on
}
```

Comment: Took a second to figure out your meaning here. I added the 'click tr' even to the javascript file for the "index" template and brought over the highlighting behavior (selected class) inside that event. Works great! Thanks for your help!